# Cordova add platform android error

Tags: android, cordova

Creating android project... Error:

> C:\Users\user1.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\create.bat:
>   Command failed with exit code ENOENT at ChildProcess.whenDone
>   (C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:807:12)
>
> The Path environment variable is set as :
>   C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\
>
> where JAVA_HOME is :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25 ANDROID_HOME is
>   : D:\Softwares\AndroidSDK\sdk\sdk ANDROID_SWT is:
>   D:\Softwares\AndroidSDK\sdk\sdk\tools\lib\x86_64 ANT_HOME: C:\Program
>   Files\apache-ant-1.9.4

I have tried with installing jdk 7 and 6 but still same error.. 
Can any one please help..

Comment: Wild guess: your path variable setting are may be wrong

Comment: The Path variables are correct. I tried on different machine and its working fine but not on my system.

Comment: just type "cordova" in cmd and check if you have correctly configured.Also check by typing "ant" , "java" commands..

Comment: "cordova", "ant", "java" commands are working

Comment: and have you installed android sdk? (does command android work?) Maybe try to run check_reqs.bat

Comment: check_reqs.bat runs successfully with mesage : Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the issue is resolved.. My ComSpec environment variable whose value is %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe had a ";" at the end, which was causing this issue. I just removed ";" and yuppie.. it worked..

Answer (score 2):

What actually happened here is that `cmd` command can not be found.

I got the same problem today on Windows 7, NodeJS 5.4, Cordova 5.4.1. `cordova platform add android` failed to work because of unknown issue. However, `cordova -d platform add android` actually showed some clues. `cordova platform add android` is a wrapper over the real command: `cmd /s /c "..../create.bat" ...`. When you executed that command manually, you would know the underlying error: `'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

I have to change `ComSpec` environment variable from `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe` to `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;%SystemRoot%\system32` to make it work.

If it does not work, please add `%SystemRoot%\system32` intp `PATH` as well

Answer (score 0):

**You've entered the wrong command**. 
**Try this**

```
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

**fix is here** (FOR WINDOWS ONLY)

I am facing the same problem of Build then i finally found out the solution.

**SOLUTION**
So You must have the Android Api 23 in order for this command to work.
Error of Daemon process will be solve after installing the Api 23 and extra 
build tools and run command 
COMMAND : cordova build android --release
I am sure this fix would help you to solve the problem.

**STEPS**
1. First check the version of android through this COMMAND:
   cordova platform help 
2. Run the build command after installing the Api 23 and extra build tools.
3. If Even this not work then Try add the variable in the 
 Environment variables > System variables > 
 add _JAVA_OPTIONS and value = -Xmx512M

Then Run cordova build android --release

BUT FIRSTLY SET UP THE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES 
[Environment Variable setup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5InU.png)
[android API 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLI0J.png)

**COPY FROM HERE** 
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:-

1. **USER VARIABLES**
   **PATH** 
   C:\Ruby23\bin;C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ANDROID_SDK\tools;%SystemRo
   ot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
2. **SYSTEM VARIABLES** 
   **ADD NAME AND VALUE** 
   2.1  **_JAVA_OPTIONS**   -Xmx512M 
   2.2  **ANDROID_HOME**    C:\ANDROID_SDK 
   2.3  **PATH** -> 
   C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs;C:\Gradle\gradle-4.0\bin;C:\ANDROID_SDK\tools;%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;